# why i can not open an Excel(xls) with HSSF

Tags: java, apache-poi, poi-hssf

Im getting an error when i am trying to open an Excel sheet with MS office 2003.
This excel sheet is created using HSSFWorkbook immplementing the usermodel scope
org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel

What are the differences between usermodel and event model?

Thanks

Comment: Without telling us what error you're seeing it's going to be kind of hard for anybody to help you.

Comment: Did you try with the latest version of Apache POI?

Comment: Thanks, the error is: the document looks empty when i use MS-Office 2003, in 2007 version the file looks good. In the code the file is created XLS file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usermodel is for creating, reading, and modifying XLS files.  The eventmodel is for fast reading of XLS files.  If all you are doing is reading spreadsheet data you should use the eventmodel (smaller memory footprint but harder to use).  If you are modifying spreadsheet data then you should use the usermodel (higher memory footprint but simpler to work with).

[More info](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, the error is: the document looks empty when i use MS-Office 2003, in 2007 version the file looks good. In the code the file is created XLS file. Thanks